# rails partial doesn't receive variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My application has a Server and Domain modules such that server has_many domains and domain belongs_to server.

I'm trying to render a partial in the Server controller:

```
  def get_domain_checkboxes
      @domains = Domain.find_by(:server_id => params[:id])  
      render :partial => 'servers/domain_checkboxes', :layout => nil
  end
```

The partial '_domain_checkboxes.html.erb' contains:

```
<% @domains.each do |domain| %>
    domain.url
<% end %>
```

But I get an error when going to 'servers/3/get_domain_checkboxes' route and the trace says:

```
Started GET "/servers/3/get_domain_checkboxes" for ::1 at 2015-12-18 05:03:08 +0200
Processing by ServersController#get_domain_checkboxes as HTML
  Parameters: {"server_id"=>"3"}
  Domain Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."server_id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Rendered servers/_domain_checkboxes.html.erb (1.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <% @domains.each do |domain| %>
    2:     hello
    3: <% end %>
  app/views/servers/_domain_checkboxes.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_servers__domain_checkboxes_html_erb___2806237560631891313_70206341448100'
  app/controllers/servers_controller.rb:71:in `get_domain_checkboxes'
```

Tried anything for past hour. Probably something simple that I'm missing?

EDIT:

Tried `@domains = Domain.find_by(:server_id => params[:server_id])`  instead but still get an error:

```
Started GET "/servers/3/get_domain_checkboxes" for ::1 at 2015-12-18 05:09:43 +0200
Processing by ServersController#get_domain_checkboxes as HTML
  Parameters: {"server_id"=>"3"}
  Domain Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."server_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["server_id", 3]]
  Rendered servers/_domain_checkboxes.html.erb (1.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for #<Domain:0x007fb465810738>):
    1: <% @domains.each do |domain| %>
    2:     hello
    3: <% end %>
  app/views/servers/_domain_checkboxes.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_servers__domain_checkboxes_html_erb___2806237560631891313_70206341448100'
  app/controllers/servers_controller.rb:71:in `get_domain_checkboxes'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change:

```
@domains = Domain.find_by(:server_id => params[:id])
```

to

```
@domains = Domain.where(:server_id => params[:server_id])
```

Comment: Still get an error though a bit different. See edited question

Comment: @Tom - `find_by` returns first element matching the query, while `where` returns collection of all elements matching the query.